# What's the best way to preload all types of images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, pagespeed

I want to preload all images on my page.

My page has some images used directly as links, i.e. as `img` tags within an `a` tag, as well as some images which are in the `background-image` property of some spans.

What's the best way to preload them all? I notice that a lot of the preload scripts seem to assume that the images will be loaded within image tags. For example, I've implemented this script: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/preloadimagesplus.shtml

But it doesn't make a difference on my page where certain spans when hovered over should have a new background. There's still a pause on my page when the user hovers over an element, before the right images background shows up.

### Edit

I know about using sprites, my question is asking for a solution apart from sprites.

Comment: This question it is too "big". Have you searched on Google? There are many ways to answer you.

Comment: I have, but referring to preload functions like this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/preloadimagesplus.shtml, it doesn't make a difference on my page where many images are used as span backgrounds.

Comment: You could potentially "abuse" img tags using a similar js function and then use some css: "display: none;" on the elements so they load with the page itself. But then again, sprites would make this much simpler.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery plugin was featured on http://www.unheap.com a while ago. Could this be of service?

http://nick-jonas.github.io/imageloader/

I do notice that the Github repository is "unavailable due to DMCA takedown", but maybe it could point you in the right direction.

Another solution might be this plugin:

https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL